# How to run animation after specified duration in proper way?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Let's say I have 3 shapes in `Stack` widget which needs to be moved from point A to point B. I would like to start these 3 animations after specified delay 0ms 1000ms 2000ms .. . So for that I have 3 separated `AnimationController` objects but I don't see constructor parameter like `delay:`. I tried to run `forward` method 3 times in loop using

```
int delay = 0;
for (final AnimationController currentController in controllers) {
   Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay), () {
       currentController.forward(from: value);
    });
   delay += 1000;
}
```

or

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay));
currentController.forward(from: value);
```

or using `Timer` class instead of `Future` but it doesn't work properly. In foreground its working good but when I move application to **background** and go back to **foreground** the gap between each shape disappearing and they are in the same position sticked together and moving like one shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a stateful widget like below. Change the animation according to your needs.

```
class SlideUpWithFadeIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;
  final Curve curve;

  SlideUpWithFadeIn({@required this.child, @required this.curve, this.delay});

  @override
  _SlideUpWithFadeInState createState() => _SlideUpWithFadeInState();
}

class _SlideUpWithFadeInState extends State<SlideUpWithFadeIn>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animController;
  Animation<Offset> _animOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1250));
    final curve =
        CurvedAnimation(curve: widget.curve, parent: _animController);
    _animOffset =
        Tween<Offset>(begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.75), end: Offset.zero)
            .animate(curve);

    if (widget.delay == null) {
      _animController.forward();
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
        _animController.forward();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      child: SlideTransition(
        position: _animOffset,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      opacity: _animController,
    );
  }
}
```

And use it like

```
SlideUpWithFadeIn(
   child: ...,
   delay: 0,
   curve: ...,
),
SlideUpWithFadeIn(
   child: ...,
   delay: 1000,
   curve: ...,
),
SlideUpWithFadeIn(
   child: ...,
   delay: 2000,
   curve: ...,
),
```